# Writing SQL Query in Up Method in C# MVC EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am developing an mvc App using Code First Approach. I want to generate VarcharID Based on the Identity Column Value. I know How to Achieve this in SQL. I want to Know how can I write the following SQL Query in VoidUp() Method
SQL Query I want to Write

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeMaster](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[PreFix] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[EmployeeNo]  AS ([PreFix]+ RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(7)), 7))    PERSISTED,
[EmployeeName] VARCHAR(50),
CONSTRAINT [PK_AutoInc] PRIMARY KEY ([ID] ASC)
)
```

My Code in Migration.cs Void Up method

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.Employees",
            c => new
                {
                    ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    EmployeePrefix = c.String(),
                    EmployeeEmpNo = c.String(), // Want to Change stuff Here
                    EmployeeName = c.String(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);
```

Comment: what i s varcharID based? An ID field which is of type `varchar`?

Comment: @RBT Well varcharID is a Combination of a Prefix i.e. and an ID generated . Something Like EMP001

Comment: I suggest you use GUID Type in Id field.

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh Well that Conflicts The real Purpose of having a varchar id. as I said before I want a way to add prefix **EMP** to the system Auto Generated ID.

Comment: @abdulhannan I think you must create id generator with custom format.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the data you need in "Seed" method of "Configuration.cs" file. You can find an example [here](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). Your code will look smth like this:

```
foreach (var entity in context.EmployeeMaster.Where(em => string.IsNullOrEmpty(em.EmployeeNo))
{
    var idStr = "0000000" + entity.Id.ToString();
    entity.EmployeeNo = entity.Prefix + idStr.SubString(idStr.Length - 7);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Even if the link is enough to provide enough information to solve the problem, it is advisable to post the core answer along with the link. That way, if the link goes offline, people will still be able to find the answer.

Comment: Of course its obvious but how can I achieve the Actual Task (Scenario) I wrote Above.